# How to buy Apple products with Bitcoin?

Tags: merchants

How can I buy Apple products? I want to buy the new iPad Mini, and I'd use Gyft to convert BTC to Amazon credit, but the new iPad is not yet on Amazon. Is there any way to buy the new iPad Mini, either directly through Apple or through a 3rd party?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking for a service recommendation, and too broad, because it doesn't specify necessary information such as the country you want to buy the product in.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding anything clever (I am still pretty new to this), you can simply convert your Bitcoins to your local currency through a third party.  There will be a transaction fee (I imagine), but I doubt Apple is going to hop on the BTC wagon anytime soon and their business model, AFAIK, won't allow for the same lever of third-party integration as Amazon does.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this but I don't want to have to pay tax on BTC -> USD. That conversion would be taxed as a sale of assets, I think.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: there are Apple Product websites listed on the Hidden Wiki, supposedly selling Apple products directly for BTC.